# NullPointerException in p:barchar tag when use Webfilter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm having the following project:

- JAVA EE8 - EAR, EJB and WEB package - JAVA 11 - Maven
- JSF 2.3 and Primefaces version 10

And i do deployments in Payara server 5.2021.5, and develop in Intellij Idea Ultimate latest version. After login, the home or dashboard show a [Primefaces bar chart](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/components/charts?id=barchart), however, I'm obtain this issue with p:barChart tag:

[image: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception]

So I'm get a NullPointerException in line `filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);` but i dont understand why. I suppose that Primefaces send some headers parameters inside request and for any reason that content is unavailable. This is my securityFilter code:

```java
@WebFilter(filterName = "SecurityFilter", urlPatterns = {"/dashboard/*"})
public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
                HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
                String currentModule = req.getRequestURI();
                EntityUser user = (EntityUser) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
                if (user == null) {
                    String expired =  new StringBuilder().append(req.getContextPath()).append("/error/expired.xhtml").toString();
                    String facesRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest).getHeader("Faces-Request");
                    if(facesRequest == null){
                        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
                        httpResponse.sendRedirect(expired);
                    }
                } else {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    List<String> paths = (List<String>) req.getSession().getAttribute("paths");
                    boolean valContext = paths.stream().anyMatch(currentModule::endsWith);
                    if (!valContext) {
                        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
                        httpResponse.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/error/forbidden.xhtml");
                    }
                }
                if (!servletResponse.isCommitted()) {
                    filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            throw new IOException("Error IOException in SecurityFilter.doFilter:", ie);
        } catch (ServletException se) {
            throw new ServletException("Error IOException en SecurityFilter.doFilter:", se);
        }
    }
}
```

My dashboard view is **@Named @ViewScoped** but I think that it is irrelevant. Then Someone can think of the cause of this error, might it need a dependency?, it is not possible to implement a chart if you use filters?it is a problem with the library of primefaces or it is a coding error of mine?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `SecurityFilter`, the `NullPointerException` happend at `org.primefaces.component.charts.ChartRenderer` and just passed through your `SecurityFilter`.

Intellij Idea marked `Security Filter` with blue because it is your class and you can edit it.

The problem is in your `chart.xhtml` file or maybe in the bean. If you recently migrated to PrimeFaces 10 then don't confuse [Old Primefaces charts showcase](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml) with the [New PrimeFaces charts showcase](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/chartjs/bar/bar.xhtml?jfwid=72fc7).

If you want to use the old PrimeFaces charts replace

```html
<p:barChar value="#{chartBean.chart}"/>
```

with

```html
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{chartBean.chart}"/>
```

And set all the properties like `min`, `max`, `chartExtender`, `legendPosition`, `dataFormat` in the bean, see the examples in the first showcase.